# HttpClient Upload Multiple Files - can I avoid server bottleneck?

Tags: c#, performance, dotnet-httpclient

So I currently have 3 sets of small files being generated (think about 1-2 per second per set), which I'd like to upload to a server in a timely manner. The files aren't large, but due to the number of them, it seems to clog up the server. Here's my current implementation:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, _serverUri);

MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
request.Content = form;

HttpContent content1 = new ByteArrayContent(filePart1);
content1.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("filePart1");
content1.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "filePart1";
form.Add(content1);

HttpContent content2 = new ByteArrayContent(filePart2);
content2.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("filePart2");
content2.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "filePart2";
form.Add(content2);

_httpClient.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith((response) =>
{
        ProcessResponse(response.Result);
});
```

Where filePart1 & filePart2 represent a file from one of the data sets, so there's 3 of these, one for each set of files running concurrently.

What I'd like to know, is if there's a better way to accomplish this, since the current method seems to clog up the server with its bombardment of files. Would it be possible to somehow open a stream for each set of files and send each file as a chunk somehow? Should I wait for the server to respond before sending the next file?

Comment: Your suggestion about sending the files sequentially, 1 by 1, sounds like a good idea from client side, but might only be a band-aid. It probably would be a good idea to look into spinning up a couple of extra servers and load-balancing them if you are seeing performance hits.

Comment: " the current method seems to clog up the server" - symptoms?

Comment: I was receiving timeouts for packets after a certain time period, probably because I wasn't waiting for the server response before sending the next. Adding a .Wait() to the end of the above code fixes that, but the whole process is still much slower than I'd like.